# why the Code Does not work if changing the order of statement?

Tags: javascript, html, function, scope, addeventlistener

[My CodePen](https://codepen.io/oscar-wang13/pen/wvaeYLO?editors=1111)

```
dataPanel.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (event.target.matches('.fa-thumbs-up')) {
    let score = parseInt(event.target.parentElement.children[2].innerText)
    event.target.parentElement.children[2].innerText = score + 1
  } else if (event.target.matches('.fa-thumbs-down')) {
    let score = parseInt(event.target.parentElement.children[2].innerText)
    event.target.parentElement.children[2].innerText = score - 1
  } else if (event.target.matches('.btn-danger')) {
    let tr = event.target.parentElement.parentElement
    tr.remove()
  } 
})
```

Currently, the function works, but I don't understand if I put "let score..." before "if satement", the btn-danger will not work and the codePen will show "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined". Is it about the function scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dataPanel` is essentially the element containing everything, and you've added the `click` listener to it.

Depending on where you click inside `dataPanel`, that click event target might not have a third child (`children[2]`) and therefore, will cause an error saying you cannot read property innerText of undefined.

The reason why there is no error when your `let score` is inside those if conditions is that those if conditions ensure that the event target has `children[2]` defined.

Comment: @Oscar make sure you set mark it as answered if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because your invoked children elements exists only when at least one of the first two if conditions is true.

For example if you click '.btn-danger' the children[2] array or index do not exists, and if exists then children[2].innerText might not get parsed to an integer ready for substraction on the next line, because they do not belong to current html pattern scope defined by the event.